# Bootstrap 3: работа JS во всех табах

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.

Есть шаблон на Bootstrap 3, в котором реализованы вкладки (tab). Есть три вкладки, в каждой находится форма с JS-калькулятором чекбоксов. Проблема в том, что калькулятор работает в первой вкладке, но не работает в других. В чем может быть проблема?

Скрипт калькулятора подключен перед закрывающим тегом боди.

Скрипт:

```
var Calculator = {
selectedGroups: [],
sum: 0,

isGroupSelected: function(groupId) {
    return this.selectedGroups.indexOf(groupId) != -1;
},

addSelected: function(groupId, amount) {
    if (!this.isGroupSelected(groupId)) {
        this.changeSum(amount);
    }
    this.selectedGroups.push(groupId);
},

removeSelected: function(groupId, amount) {
    if (!this.isGroupSelected(groupId)) {
        return;
    }
    var groupIndex = this.selectedGroups.indexOf(groupId);
    this.selectedGroups.splice(groupIndex, 1);
    if (!this.isGroupSelected(groupId)) {
        this.changeSum(-amount);
    }
},

onSelect: function(groupId, amount, elem) {
    if (elem.checked) {
        this.addSelected(groupId, amount);
    } else {
        this.removeSelected(groupId, amount);
    }
},

changeSum: function(amount) {
    this.sum += amount;
    this.showSum();
},

showSum: function() {
    document.getElementById ('r').innerHTML = this.sum;
    document.getElementById('def_sum').value = document.getElementById('r').innerHTML;
}
}
```

Часть формы

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(1, 10, this)" value="Чекбокс 1" />Чекбокс 1
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(2, 10, this)" value="Чекбокс 2" />Чекбокс 2
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(3, 10, this)" value="Чекбокс 3" />Чекбокс 3
```

Я так понимаю, что все формы сразу загружаются во всех вкладках в фоне, потому скрипт срабатывает только в первой вкладке. Но как решить эту проблему?

Comment: в чём заключается "калькулятор работает в первой вкладке, но не работает в других"? вы отслеживали изменение переменной `selectedGroups` при нажатии на других вкладках и есть ли какие-то ошибки в консоли? html табов желательно представить весь, возможно проблема в нём

Comment: 1. В чем заключается "не работает"? На первой вкладке калькулятор суммирует выделенные чекбоксы. Переходим на другие вкладки и выделяем чекбоксы - скрипт их не суммирует.
2. В консоли пишет только, что не удалось выполнить скрипт калькулятора.

Comment: а если на первой вкладке ничего не делать, а сразу попробовать посчитать на второй, то считает? если так написать на всех вкладках `onclick="Calculator.onSelect(1, 10, this)"` то исходя из кода вашей функции она будет работать только на одном нажатом чекбоксе, все другие не будут работать.

Comment: В том и дело, что считает только на первой вкладке. Решил вопрос тем, что присвоил каждой вкладке свою копию скрипта калькулятора с разными именами функции.